# vbc.exe.config file has incorrect bindings when built with azure dev ops ci

Tags: .net, azure-pipelines

I have a solution with a vb web project and a c# web project, both use nuget and packages.config to include both Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform version= 3.6.0 and Microsoft.Net.Compilers version 4.2.0, the c# project includes the correct vbc.exe.config file when deploying to the server (with the correct binding redirects) while the vb project uses later (and incorrect) bindings for the redirects (i.e. those aren't the dll's that are included in the roslyn folder in the bin folder).  Both projects are targeting framework 4.8

Of course this causes dynamic compilation of the aspx files to fail as vbc.exe can't load the assemblies that are referenced.

Does anyone know what causes the wrong vbc.exe.config file to be included?  Building locally with VS 2022 (17.4.3) works just fine for both projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have an exact answer as to what was going on, it seems to have been a buggy caching issue.  I "solved" the problem by deleting everything in the _work## directory on the build server.  I don't know what component was having the problem, but that fixed it.